# Flatten rows by expanding columns based on number of rows per ID

Tags: r

Supposing data like this, with multiple rows per ID:

```
z <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4),VA=c(1,2,3,1,2,5,7,8),VB=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","b","c"),VC=c(1,2,3,1,2,8,10,12))

ID  VA   VB   VC
1   1    a    1
1   2    b    2
1   3    c    3
2   1    a    1
2   2    b    2
3   5    c    8
4   7    b    10
4   8    c    12
```

I would like to collapse to 1 row per ID, with as many columns as I need to support the largest number of original rows present for any Id; (in this example 3 rows for ID=1):

```
ID  VA1   VA2   VA3   VB1   VB2   VB3   VC
1   1     2     3     a     b     c      2.0
2   1     2     a     b     NA    NA     1.5
3   5     NA    NA    c     NA    NA     8.0
4   7     8     NA    b     c     NA    15.0
```

Also, note how some columns (VA, VB) could be "flattened" and others (VC) could be aggregated.

I do not want to turn the values of any cell into a column name since the values can vary too widely.  But the number of rows for any given ID will be small so I thought this would be an ideal flattening approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `dcast` from `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(z)`), convert the 'VC' column to `numeric` class,  replace the values with the `mean` of 'VC' grouped by 'ID', and use `dcast` which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  In the devel version, a sequence column can be created with `rowid`.  Otherwise, we may have to do `z[, N:= 1:.N, by = ID]` and then use `dcast(z, ID+VC~N, value.var= c('VA', 'VB'), sep='')`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.7+
 setDT(z)[, VC:= as.numeric(VC)][, VC:= mean(VC), by = ID]
 dcast(z, ID+VC~rowid(ID), value.var=c('VA', 'VB'), sep='')
 #   ID   VC VA1 VA2 VA3 VB1 VB2 VB3
#1:  1  2.0   1   2   3   a   b   c
#2:  2  1.5   1   2  NA   a   b  NA
#3:  3  8.0   5  NA  NA   c  NA  NA
#4:  4 11.0   7   8  NA   b   c  NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Looks brilliant however rowid appears to be unavailable to me. I'm on R 3.2.2 and it says 1.9.6 is the latest version of data.table; (on Windows).

Comment: @JohnnyStrings   As I mentioned in the description, you don't need `rowid`.  With `1.9.6`, the sequence column can be created by `df1[, N:= 1:.N, by = ID]`

Comment: @AkhilNair  Updated the post.